# Determine a conserved quantity in a dynamical system Lotka-Volterra

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems

I have a two state dynamical system. The two state variables are $P$ and $Z$ and $a,b,c,d$ are parameters. The system equations are:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{dP}{dt}=a\cdot P-b\cdot PZ=P\left(a-bZ\right), \\
\frac{dZ}{dt}=c\cdot PZ-d\cdot Z=Z\left(cP-d\right).
\end{equation*}

Multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{PZ}$ gives:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{dP}{dt}\frac{1}{PZ}=a\frac{1}{Z}-b, \\
\frac{dZ}{dt}\frac{1}{PZ}=c-d\frac{1}{P}.
\end{equation*}

Multiplying with the original system equation gives:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{PZ}\frac{dP}{dt}\frac{dZ}{dt}=\frac{dZ}{dt}\left(a\frac{1}{Z}-b\right),
 \\
\frac{1}{PZ}\frac{dP}{dt}\frac{dZ}{dt}=\frac{dP}{dt}\left(c-d\frac{1}{P}\right).
\end{equation*}

Taking the difference of the last two equations gives:
$0=\frac{dZ}{dt}\left(a\frac{1}{Z}-b\right)+\frac{dP}{dt}\left(d\frac{1}{P}-c\right)$

By the chain rule, the total time derivative of my conserved quantity is:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{d}{dt}E\left(P,Z\right)=\frac{dZ}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial Z}E\left(P,Z\right)+\frac{dP}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial P}E\left(P,Z\right)
\end{equation*}

so then the following should hold:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial Z}E\left(P,Z\right)=\left(a\frac{1}{Z}-b\right)~\text{and}~
\frac{\partial}{\partial P}E\left(P,Z\right)=\left(d\frac{1}{P}-c\right)
\end{equation*}

so

$
E\left(P,Z\right)=\int\left(a\frac{1}{Z}-b\right)\partial Z=\int\left(d\frac{1}{P}-c\right)\partial P
$
$=a\ln{Z}-bZ+C_{Z}\left(P\right)=d\ln{P}-cP+C_{P}\left(Z\right)$

Finally:

\begin{equation*}
E\left(P,Z\right)=a\ln{Z}+dln{P}-bZ-cP
\end{equation*}

**Edit** and this quantity is conserved! I had a bad calculus mistake.

Comment: A nice context introduction would help.

Comment: You can go ahead and delete the question, I believe.

Comment: Thank you for keeping the question up and updating your solution! However, I couldn't help but wonder if the equation before your final solution should actually read as follows: $$(,)=∫(\frac{1}{}−)∂+∫(\frac{1}{}−)∂$$ $$E(P,Z)=\ln{}-+_()+ \ln{}−+_()$$ $$\therefore (,)=\ln{}++\ln{}−+\tilde{C}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited the original post to include the correct derivation. My mathematical weakness showed when I confused integration with differentiation!